# auto load data in ajax how to change it into click button

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

what happen in the code is that everytime i choose in multiple drop down it fetch the data what i want to happen is to click the button first then it will fetch the data...... thank u guys got the code in here  https://www.webslesson.info/2018/05/ajax-live-data-search-using-multi-select-dropdown-in-php.html

```
<?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", "root", "");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM tbl_customer ORDER BY Country ASC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Ajax Live Data Search using Multi Select Dropdown in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Ajax Live Data Search using Multi Select Dropdown in PHP</h2><br />

   <select name="multi_search_filter" id="multi_search_filter" multiple class="form-control selectpicker">
   <?php
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
    echo '<option value="'.$row["Country"].'">'.$row["Country"].'</option>'; 
   }
   ?>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden_country" id="hidden_country" />
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Customer Name</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>City</th>
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query='')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
  $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());
  var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
  load_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
//fetch.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbattendancelibrary", "root", "");

if($_POST["query"] != '')
{
 $search_array = explode(",", $_POST["query"]);
 $search_text = "'" . implode("', '", $search_array) . "'";
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_customer 
 WHERE Country IN (".$search_text.") 
 ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer ORDER BY CustomerID DESC";
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$total_row = $statement->rowCount();

$output = '';

if($total_row > 0)
{
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '
  <tr>
   <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["Address"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
  </tr>
  ';
 }
}
else
{
 $output .= '
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" align="center">No Data Found</td>
 </tr>
 ';
}

echo $output;


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fires an ajax call because of this code:

```
 $('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
  $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());
  var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
  load_data(query);
 });
```

If you want to fire when clicking on a button, you will need to put in HTML for the button first. Then use the id for load_data event, for example you will have a button called '#btn_search':

```
 $('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
  $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());
 });

 $('#btn_search').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
  load_data(query);
 });
```

Your full HTML above becomes like this:

```
<?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", "root", "");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM tbl_customer ORDER BY Country ASC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Ajax Live Data Search using Multi Select Dropdown in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Ajax Live Data Search using Multi Select Dropdown in PHP</h2><br />

   <select name="multi_search_filter" id="multi_search_filter" multiple class="form-control selectpicker">
   <?php
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
    echo '<option value="'.$row["Country"].'">'.$row["Country"].'</option>'; 
   }
   ?>
   </select>
   <input id="btn_search" type="button" value="Filter" />
   <input type="hidden" name="hidden_country" id="hidden_country" />
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Customer Name</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>City</th>
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query='')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#multi_search_filter').change(function(){
  $('#hidden_country').val($('#multi_search_filter').val());
 });

 $('#btn_search').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = $('#hidden_country').val();
  load_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
```